# Read string in XML format and update with a for loop in PL SQL

Tags: xml, for-loop, plsql

i am new to PL SQL and need to update a column of many records.
The column is basically a string formatted in xml.
Here is an example:

```
<indexes>
<index>
    <date_format>dd-MM-yyyy</date_format>
    <name>ID_TEST</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>123456789</value>
</index>
<index>
    <date_format>dd-MM-yyyy</date_format>
    <name>NUMBER_TEST</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>123</value>
</index>
```

**I need to add a new tag at the beginning of all index tags, as shown in the example:**

```
<indexes>
<index>
    <NEW_TAG>abcdef</NEW_TAG>
    <date_format>dd-MM-yyyy</date_format>
    <name>ID_TEST</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>123456789</value>
</index>
<index>
    <NEW_TAG>abcdef</NEW_TAG>
    <date_format>dd-MM-yyyy</date_format>
    <name>NUMBER_TEST</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <value>123</value>
</index>
```

I thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
select appendchildxml(
xmltype(your_xml)
, '/indexes/index[1]' -- replace the 1 with index instance number
, xmlelement("NEW_TAG")
).getclobval()
into my_clob
from dual;
```